# Java Web Start Application works with Java 6, but only if Java 7 is completely uninstalled. (Win7)

Tags: java, windows-7, batch-file, java-web-start

We are using a web-based KVM switch which opens up a Java Web Start launcher in order to boot the console.  When I run it with Java 6, update 43,  everything works great.  Then, I install Java 7 update 17 alongside it, and it gets a socket connection error.  I took the liberty of writing a simple batch script which forcibly chooses the Java home as well as the web start application. I then saved the jnlp file which is downloaded so that I could call it on a whim.  I am by no means a Java developer, so I apologize for any offensive practices.

```bat
set JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6"
%JAVA_HOME%\bin\javaws.exe   "C:\opt\kvm\ui.jnlp"
```

Here is the connection exception that I receive.

```
java.io.IOException: JNLP Jar download failure.
at com.sun.javaws.LaunchDownload.validateResults(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.LaunchDownload.downloadJarFiles(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.LaunchDownload.downloadEagerorAll(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.downloadResources(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareResources(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareAllResources(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.launch(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)'
```

I was wondering if you know of any reasons why Java would have different behavior when multiple versions of Java are installed?  The best explaination that I can come up with is that there is a library collision.  If this is the case, then I need to find a way to manually set the library path such that only Jre6 dlls/tools will be called.  If anyone has any advice, I  would be extremely grateful. I have also attached the internal jnlp data.  Thank you very much for your time.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- JNLP File IRP EMS     -->
<jnlp
  spec="6.0+"
  codebase="https://<IP-Address>">
  <information>
    <title>TrippLite UI</title>
    <vendor>TrippLite</vendor>
    <homepage href="http://www.tripplite.com"/>
    <description kind="short">TrippLite Manager</description>
    <icon href="minicom_desktop.gif"/> 
  </information>

  <security>
      <all-permissions/>
  </security>
  <resources>
    <j2se version="1.6+" initial-heap-size="256m" java-vm-args="-Xnoclassgc -    XX:PermSize=64m" 
        href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/> 
        <jar href="./boot.jar"/>
    <jar href="./app.jar"/>
    <jar href="./vendor.jar"/>
    <jar href="./miglayout15-swing.jar"/>
    <jar href="./jnlp.jar"/>
<jar href="./xstream-1.3.1.jar"/>
<jar href="./xpp3_min-1.1.4c.jar"/>
<nativelib href="./plugin.jar"/>

    <property name="devport" value="900"/>       
  </resources>
  <application-desc main-class="com.minicom.app.video.ui.ShowLogin">
  </application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

### Update

I ran the script with -verbose and got the following output. I am new to SO, so I can't post images.  Here is the link.

https://raw.github.com/marvins/temp_images/master/with_setting.png

It now appears that the problem is because the vm is calling on jre7's javaw.exe file.  Do you know how I could override the "-Djnlpx.jvm=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\javaws.exe and replace it with jre6?  I am trying to use different forms of "-J-Djnlpx.jvm=" and it gives an appearance similar to the one below.  It shows it there, but doesn't replace the value.

Is there a more appropriate way of forcing the proper javaws?

```
%JAVA_HOME%\bin\javaws.exe  "-J-Djnlpx.jvm=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\javaw.exe" -verbose "C:\opt\kvm\ui.jnlp"
```

Comment: You should also check the `CLASSPATH` and `PATH` variables. It should be possible to have multiple Java's installed and have no conflicts.

Comment: +1 had similar experience in the past and never solved it (sorry). App would work with 1.5, but ONLY if 1.6 was installed too - even though it never actually have used it... very odd.

Comment: Your descriptor says `<j2se version="1.6+"`; if you need to run on 1.6, try to specify `version="1.6"`

Comment: I just removed the + from both of the entries in the JNLP and it didn't seem to fix it. Good point though.  I am testing the script with `set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%"\bin; %PATH%" and that doesn't solve it either.  Finally, I tried `set CLASSPATH=%JAVA_HOME%\lib to no avail.  Thanks for the input.

Comment: Is that the full stacktrace?  There isn't a nested exception underneath the first one?  Make sure you look for all available information.

Comment: The image shows that it is using the Java 7 javaw.exe but is pulling in the jar files from your jre6 directory.  When you updated to Java 7 it probably changed the webstart executable in the browser, but you still have the JAVA_HOME environment variable set to jre6.  You could either try changing the JAVA_HOME to the jre7 or use the java console in Control Panel and disable the jre7 install.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After digging around, I uninstalled Java 7, got a working configuration, copied the output of -verbose with the javaws.exe, then integrated that into my script.  Finally, I reinstalled all java versions and it now works.  Here is my script.

```
set JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6"
set CLASSPATH=%JAVA_HOME%\lib\deploy.jar

set BOOTCP=%JAVA_HOME%\lib\javaws.jar;%JAVA_HOME%\lib\deploy.jar;%JAVA_HOME%\lib\plugin.jar
set SECPOL=file:%JAVA_HOME%\lib\security\javaws.policy
set SPLASHPORT="-Djnlpx.splashport=49688"

%JAVA_HOME%\bin\javaw.exe -Xbootclasspath/a:%BOOTCP% -classpath %CLASSPATH% -Djava.security.policy=%SECPOL% -DtrustProxy=true -Xverify:remote -Djnlpx.home=%JAVA_HOME%\bin -Dsun.aws.warmpu=true -Djnlpx.origFilenameArg=C:\opt\kvm\ui.jnlp -Djnlpx.remove=false -Xnoclassgc -XX:PermSize=64m -Xms1028m -Djnlpx.heapsize=1028m,NULL %SPLASHPORT% com.sun.javaws.Main C:\opt\kvm\ui.jnlp
```

It is very ugly, however that is verbatim what it asked for.  I didn't realize that all java tools are just the same JVM call with modifications to the main.  It makes sense now, but as a C++ guy, this stuff is a little magic.

It still doesn't answer how to configure this yourself using only javaws, but it does solve the problem using the output of it.

Thanks again for your help.

Comment: This solved that annoying problem for me, thank you for posting this answer !